# Call a method on a trait when that method is more constrained than the trait

Tags: rust

I am implementing a tree.  The tree can have 2 types of leaves (one any kind of sized data, the other for storing variable length characters).  So something like

```
struct Tree<L : Leaf> {
    parent : L::Item,
    leaf : L,
}

struct LeafArr<T> {
    elements : [T; 8],
}

struct LeafStr {
    elements : [u8; 8],
}

trait Leaf {
    type Item;
}

impl<T> Leaf for LeafArr<T> {
    type Item=T;
}
impl Leaf for LeafStr {
    type Item=char;
}
```

In a different file, I want to define a function that checks if the tree contains an item.

```
impl<L : Leaf> Tree<L> where L::Item : Eq {
    fn tree_contains(&self, search: &L::Item) -> bool {
        &self.parent == search ||
        self.leaf.contains(search) // direct this call
    }
}

impl<T : Eq> LeafArr<T> {
    fn contains0(&self, search :  &T) -> bool {
        for k in 0 .. 8 {
            if &self.elements[k] == search {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}

impl LeafStr {
    fn contains0(&self, search :  &char) -> bool {
        // erroneously simplified for the sake of the question
        for c in unsafe { std::str::from_utf8_unchecked(&self.elements) }
            .chars()
        {
            if &c == search {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

How do I make it so `&self.leaf.contains(search)` calls the appropriate contains0 method?  The contains0 method's require Item : Eq, which the Leaf trait doesn't provide, but the where clause on tree_contains does provide.

I'm open to suggestions for other ways to define the types and traits.  But requiring the tree to only store Eq items isn't acceptable, since other functions will work fine without that constraint.

I'd also prefer that the main file be as ignorant as possible as to the functionality in the subfile, for the sake of modularity.

I'd tried lots of things like making a new trait in the subfile and implementing it in various ways but I can't seem to find a way that works.

Ideally I'd want search's type to only require PartialEq but trying to keep it simple; any solution that only requires PartialEq would be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can introduce another trait, `Container`, for which your leaf types implement and constrain that `L` is a `Container` just for the `tree_contains()` method:

```
trait Container: Leaf {
    fn contains(&self, search: &Self::Item) -> bool;
}

impl<L: Leaf> Tree<L> {
    fn tree_contains(&self, search: &L::Item) -> bool
    where
        L::Item: PartialEq,
        L: Container, // <----------
    {
        &self.parent == search || self.leaf.contains(search)
    }
}

impl<T: PartialEq> Container for LeafArr<T> {
    fn contains(&self, search: &T) -> bool {
        // ... implementation snipped
    }
}

impl Container for LeafStr {
    fn contains(&self, search: &char) -> bool {
        // ... implementation snipped
    }
}
```

Change from `Eq` to `PartialEq` included as well. Full code [on the Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b6c5d3f40253d2eb61c744fb83ad8ee6).

Comment: This is a better answer than I had hoped for. I'll need some time to work through it and make sure it works in the "larger project".  But the PartialEq was supposed to be like, a tree using LeafArr storing Strings , I could search using a &str .  But I can probably figure that much out now.

Comment: @DanielV For storing `String`s and searching by `&str`, consider using [`Borrow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/trait.Borrow.html#examples) since that is how the standard `HashMap` and other collections allow for that kind of functionality.

Comment: I can't seem to find anywhere that explains why to use Borrow instead of PartialOrd/PartialEq.  PartialEq seems strictly more general than Borrow, since you could, for example, partialeq compare a tree and a slice but not borrow between them.  I'm thinking I should probably ask this as a separate question though.

Comment: Well I found this that doesn't give a real reason but seems to agree it is not great : https://github.com/rust-phf/rust-phf/issues/169

Comment: @DanielV Its not "instead of", you would use both together. Look at how [`HashMap::get`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.get) doesn't take they key type `K`, it takes some type `Q` where `K: Borrow<Q>`. So you would use the comparison between the passed in `Q` type and the values contained in your tree as `.borrow()`-ed.